# Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383

Tags: laravel, email, verification

I cant seem to send an email verification in laravel, I keep getting this error.

Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 64.233.189.108 (64.233.189.108:587), connect error 10060"

Comment: Please show your `.env` file.

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=organicev5@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls